# How to create a MessageBox in OpenGL using C++

Tags: opengl, c++

I have a game that needs results displayed upon exit with a messagebox. I have the following code that works but I need to add an integer variable to the text. 
This works:

```
MessageBox(NULL, L"Description\nline2", L"Info", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
```

But I need to say: "Description:" + num

I tried to pass a string but it won't compile:
MessageBox(NULL, L(string), L"Info", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);

Comment: Look up string formatting in C++; this a general programming question and thus more suitable to SO than GDSE.

Comment: I understand how to do this in general c++ but I think it has something to do with how my c++ is set-up. I tried passing a pointer to a string variable but it would not allow me to use L(str). Its expecting something in double quotes.

Comment: @Unity: It's general C++, as you seem to be very confused about what the `L` qualifier means for strings in C++, or how to interpret the unspecified error messages you received. This is a general Win32/C++ question and not at all related to games or OpenGL.

Comment: Josh refers to general programming as in not game related but a valid programming question suitable for http://stackoverflow.com/ . He is not referring to your general knowledge of C++- Here at gamedevSE we only ask and answer game related questions. OpenGL is not always valid as it can be used for general programming